# Solr: Searching actual items vs related items

Tags: search, solr, product

We use solr for our product search. When using solr we have the need for handling "Is a" vs "Relates to". For example, right now if I search for "knife" I get knife sharpeners much higher than I would like given that we carry so many actual knives. Given that both products have "knife" in the name (when comparing '8" chef's knife' with 'Electric knife sharpener') and they both exist in a knife category, it's very difficult in our current setup to differentiate that we want the chef knife to have a higher score for this search term.

We have an approach for this which is some sort of label tied to a product when it is categorized and put on the site that it relates to another category. So for example, the cutting boards category relates to the knives category, but the knives category is the "master" category in that case. We could achieve the differentiation we want in that case, but that requires a lot of labor and management on the merchandisers' end.

I'm curious if there is a functionality in solr that I'm not aware of that would take care of this or if it's just a matter of us needing to tweak the way we store things.

Here's an example of an 8" chef knife doc vs an electric knife sharpener doc

8 inch knife:

```
"productId": 9071,
    "productName": "8\" Chinese Chef's Knife",
    "text": [
      "8\" Chinese Chef's Knife",
      "Update International",
      "KCC-8",
      "Chinese Chef's Knives"
    ],
    "productName_exact": "8\" Chinese Chef's Knife",
    "manuf": "Update International",
    "baseSku": "KCC-8",
    "sku": [
      "KCC-8"
    ],
    "modelTypeDesc": "Chinese Chef's Knives",
    "manufId": 74,
    "categories": [
      "Chef's Knives",
      "Chinese Chef's Knives",
      "Knife Sale"
    ],        
    "type": "Product",
    "popularity": 4301,
    "displayName": "Update International (KCC-8) - 8\" Chinese Chef's Knife",
```

electric knife sharpener:

```
"productId": 3267,
    "productName": "Edlund Electric Knife Sharpener",
    "text": [
      "Edlund Electric Knife Sharpener",
      "Edlund",
      "395",
      "Electric Knife Sharpeners"
    ],
    "productName_exact": "Edlund Electric Knife Sharpener",
    "manuf": "Edlund",
    "baseSku": "395",
    "sku": [
      "395"
    ],
    "modelTypeDesc": "Electric Knife Sharpeners",
    "manufId": 22,
    "categories": [
      "Electric Knife Sharpeners",
      "Knife Sharpeners"
    ],       
    "type": "Product",
    "popularity": 53,
    "displayName": "Edlund (395) - Edlund Electric Knife Sharpener",
```

You'll see a "popularity" field on there which I thought about using, but the problem there is, given that that field is based off how well something sells, it's possible that an accessory for something might sell better than the item itself, but the term should still match the item itself first.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unless you have categorical data that indicates that a document "is a" and not "relates to", it's hard to do anything useful automagically. And since neither of your documents actually contain an element that says "Knife", it's hard to boost by that .. One possibility might be to append a "negative" boost by common terms that you want to remove from the search, or boost documents for more important items when indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a good way of doing this for those that want to know. I realized that I can assume with pretty good certainty that if a person is searching for a knife his search term will END with the word knife. If he's searching for a knife sharpener, his search term will end with the word sharpener.

Given this I was able to make a field that only indexed the last word of our product name. So in the case of the knife it would just be "knife". In the case of the knife sharpener it would just be "sharpener".

I then indexed that field and then queried against it with a much higher boost value than just the standard product name field. The important thing here is I broke up the user's search term and used only the last word. I used a pretty strict keyword tokenizer and analysis to make sure that it only matched in almost exact cases. It only has lowercase, hunspell, and synonym filters on it.

This automatically achieved exactly what I was looking for. The only caveat is that if you don't have the product properly named, it won't show up where you expect it. A good example would be a "knife set" rather than "knife". They are both knives but one won't show up as high when searching knife. But one could also argue that is working as intended.